# Binding to a field of a non-dependancy object

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-4.0, dependency-properties

In my .NET 4.0 project I've got an object that has public fields and this object neither implements INotifyPropertyChanged nor inherits DependencyObject, and it will never do. However, I need a mechanism to "bind" to fields of this object in my WPF control. I know I can't do it directly as binding requires a dependency property (or at least, properties and notifying property changes), so what can I do to implement the binding functionality I need. I've tried something like this in my WPF control:

```
    void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public float Friction
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentObject != null)
            {
                return CurrentObject.Friction;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0.0f;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentObject != null)
            {
                CurrentObject.Friction = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Friction");
            }
        }
    }

    public PlatformObjectTemplate CurrentObject
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(CurrentObjectProperty) as PlatformObjectTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CurrentObjectProperty, value);
            FirePropertyChanged("Friction");
            FirePropertyChanged("CurrentObject");
            BindShapes();
            IntersectionComboBox.SelectedItem = CurrentObject.IntersectionStaticMethod;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentObject", typeof(PlatformObjectTemplate), typeof(PlatformStaticObjectPropertyEditor), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

My WPF control implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and my `PlatformObjectTemplate` does not have properties, just public fields like `Friction`. I need to bind to my object in XAML as such:

(in my control): //DoubleUpDown is from the WPF toolkit.

```
<tk:DoubleUpDown Margin="91,10,7,0" Name="doubleUpDown1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding Friction, ElementName=window, FallbackValue=0}" />
```

(in my main window):

```
<my:PlatformStaticObjectPropertyEditor x:Name="platformStaticObjectPropertyEditor1" CurrentObject="{Binding CurrentObject, ElementName=window}" />
```

I put a breakpoint in the getter of Friction property, and it tries to bind **before** the `CurrentObject` is bound, and because it is null, I can't read the correct friction value from the object. I've tried to fire `Friction` property changed in the setter of the CurrentObject, to populate the Friction when CurrentObject gets set, but that doesn't work either.

Ok, here are two requirements:

`PlatformObjectTemplate` will **not** use properties. It will have public fields.
I need a declarative way of binding as usual, just as I used in the XAML above.

I probably have got things over-complicated, and I must be missing some stuff. What is the most "correct" and "declarative" way of doing this right, within the constraints of my requirements just above?

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in your Output window?  Your binding on the control is `Value="{Binding Friction, ElementName=window, FallbackValue=0}"` - is that referencing the root of the control, or is it referencing the window?  What happens when you fire the `Friction` property changed manually?

Comment: no, I'm not getting any binding errors in output about this binding. and yes, sorry for confusion, "window" refers to the control root itself. it's my own convention for making things simpler, i just use the "window" word to name the root, no matter if it's a control or a window.

Comment: create wrapper which implements INPC

Comment: The only other thing I can think to ask is: what does the `BindShapes` method do?

Comment: @jberger is that the only way? if yes, make it into an answer, and i'll follow that way.

Comment: @DanPuzey it has nothing to do with the "wpf binding". just something to do with my method naming. just some housekeeping method that binds (but not officially a "binding") a shape list to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object neither implements INotifyPropertyChanged nor inherits DependencyObject, and it will never. However, I need a mechanism to "bind" to fields of this object in my WPF control`

poyra, I have this same situation.  Because one cannot bind to instance fields, your best option is to create wrapper classes which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.